# Linux SSH Login w/Certificate Expiry

Tags: linux, ssh, certificate

I got a Ubuntu 16.06 Rootserver and have several other people that may need to login on it as a special user.

I don't want to send around Passwords or even private Keys.

Is it possible to generate Keys that expire in +3 Days after generation, **without touching anything on the Server?**

I.e. with a root certificate that the Server knows and I got in a secure place wich I can use to generate those Keys with a expiry date?

Answer (score 8):

> or even private Keys.

Why *would* you ever send private keys? Ask the user to generate their own keypair and have them send *you* the public key.

> Is it possible to generate Keys that expire in +3 Days after generation,

Assuming the server uses OpenSSH, there are two ways:

- **Certificates**: Supported with OpenSSH 5.4 or later, but *all* users must use OpenSSH as well – the generated certificates do not work with PuTTY or other clients.

  First generate an "authority" SSH key with `ssh-keygen` and list it in the server's configuration (using the `TrustedUserCAKeys` option), then use it to issue user certificates.

  To issue a certificate: When the user sends you their `id_rsa.pub` file, sign it with the CA key. Once signed, send the new `id_rsa.pub-cert` file back to the user.

  ```
  ssh-keygen -s ~/private/user_ca -I user_fred -n fred -V +3d fred_id_rsa.pub
  ```

  Here `-n` specifies who can log in using the cert, and `-V` sets its expiry time. (The `-I` option just sets an arbitrary name for the cert itself.)
- **authorized_keys**: Supported with OpenSSH 7.7 or later, without any client requirements. The expiry information isn't stored within the key itself, but in the server's *authorized_keys* file:

  ```
  expiry-time="20180704" ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3NzaC1lZDI1NTE...
  ```

  From manual page *sshd(8)*, the allowed time formats are `YYYYMMDD` and `YYYYMMDDHHMM[SS]` in the server's main timezone.

  Note that this method is only secure if the user is prevented from editing their authorized_keys file, otherwise they could just extend the expiry time!